# A glimpse of the Ocean

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

It begins with a challenge, a look straight in the eye

But when you take a step back see you stare into the night

Listen and act; don't get c**o**nfused **b**y a *verse*

To finish the spell you must learn to do this well first

Answer (score 1):

is it

> a puzzle

because
it begins with a challenge

> the puzzle is posted

but when you take a step back

> you start thinking about the possible solutions

listen and act dont get confuzed

> watchout for red herrings and check your logic

to finish the spell

> to be good at solving puzzles you need to know how they work